# Unbinding ng-repeat scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two `<tr>`s and an ng-repeat on each, but both perform the same operation on their child elements, like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data : filterFunc" ng-if="mode === 'something'">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item in data : filterFunc" ng-if="mode === 'somethingelse'">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Imagine, there are two types of data sets and which one is to be rendered is decided by the `mode` property at run time. So, either the first `<tr>` is rendered in the DOM or the other one.
Initially the first `<tr>` will be rendered and the associated `filterFunc` function will work properly. There's a simple drop down which has two options, one each for the two `mode`s. If you select the other mode, the second `<tr>` will be rendered and first one will be removed from the DOM.
The problem is, the `filterFunc` now is bound to both the `<tr>`s and operates on both of them. 
How do I unbind the scope or watchers for the first one let it be bound only to the second one? or any one of them at any point of time? Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6kx4ojL4/

Note: For the sake of simplicity, I have simply returned the passed-in data object as-is in `filterFunc`. Check the output in browser console. It gets called twice, i.e. for both data sets.

Comment: can you give me plunker? or try to use double equal in ng-if="mode == 'something'"

Comment: Give us more code (button and function) to understand better your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want to do exactly from your description. My first thought is that you could separate your modes in ng-if, say, use mode1 and mode2, so you can control two <tr>s separately..

Comment: The problem is the pagination function gets called twice, after the second `<tr>` is also loaded. The bindings dont get updated, instead they just add up!

Comment: As I said, it is hard for us to figure out what you want to do without the actual code, and even a simplified version of your code with some relevant details would help. As for your comment, when you say bindings don't get updated, I think there are some methods you can use such as $watch, $boradcast etc.

Comment: I understand, I've added the fiddle now.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show instead of ng-if

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in data : orderBy: 'name'" ng-show="mode === 'something'">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="item in data : orderBy: 'name'" ng-show="mode === 'somethingelse'">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Even if I do that, the problem still persists. The pagination function gets called twice, one each for the two `<tr>`s, after the second one is also loaded. I need to use the same function for both as its the same operation that is required on both.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. Check this **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vxcjw45d/1/

**If it's not what are you looking for tell me - I will delete it :)**

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <table ng-controller="myController">
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: 'name'" 
            ng-if="mode === 'something'">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: 'name'"
            ng-if="mode === 'somethingelse'">
            <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <button ng-click="changeMode()">
                    Change Mode
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        { name: 'John', age: 21 },
        { name: 'Doe', age: 33 }
    ];

    $scope.mode = 'something';

    $scope.changeMode = function() {
        if ($scope.mode === 'something') {
            $scope.mode = 'somethingelse';
        } else if ($scope.mode === 'somethingelse') {
            $scope.mode = 'something'
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I appreciate that effort @iceless :) I had to slightly edit my question as requested from the comments to it. So now there's this pagination function which operates on the table rows.

Comment: You can update my JSFiddle and add it to your question  as EDIT so that we can understand it better and  to help you :)